# Dynamic summing in a object key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

```js
var dataJson = JSON.stringify({
  "11501": {
    "Name": "11501",
    "RecipeName": "N",
    "Time": 10,
    "Ingredient1ID": 1,
    "Ingredient1Quantity": 2,
  },
  "11502": {
    "Name": "11502",
    "RecipeName": "N",
    "Time": 10,
    "Ingredient1ID": 2,
    "Ingredient1Quantity": 2,
  },
  });
var jsonobject = JSON.parse(dataJson);
element = {};

function addElement(e, t) {
  element[jsonobject[e]['Ingredient1ID']] += jsonobject[e]['Ingredient1Quantity'];
  console.log(element);
}
```

```html
 

   <button type="button" class="btn bg-purple btn-flat margin" onclick="addElement(11501,10);">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add to queue
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn bg-purple btn-flat margin" onclick="addElement(11502,10);">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add to queue item2
</button>
```

addElement is a onClick function its supposed to sum quantity of element[key] on each click, if the key exists it should add the value such as += does.

Currently it outputs Object {11001: NaN} since it has no basic value though. I can not provide basic value for the key since they are dynamic numbers example:

First click

Object {ID: Qty}

Object {11501: 2}

Object {11501: 2+2}

Is there an option to accomplish this sum functionality? It could be also an array if its easier.

https://jsfiddle.net/fxfLemtu/

Comment: i can't test your code because some parts are missing, but I suppose that addElement is called from an event and consequently the parameter "e" is the event, try to put t instead of e.

Comment: e is the id t is name

Comment: please add a complete and working code, from what you've posted you are clearly adding strings

Comment: added some more staff item id is a select field, amount input txt - but that works

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fxfLemtu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this example.
I hope I understood what you're trying to do.

```js
var queue = {};
var jsonobject = {
  "11501": {
    "Ingredient1ID": 1,
    "Ingredient1Quantity": 2,
  },
  "11502": {
    "Ingredient1ID": 2,
    "Ingredient1Quantity": 2,
  }
};

function addElement(e, t) {
  var elementId = jsonobject[e]['Ingredient1ID'];
  var elementQuantity = jsonobject[e]['Ingredient1Quantity'];
  
  if (!(elementId in queue)) {
    queue[elementId] = elementQuantity;
  } else {
    queue[elementId] += elementQuantity;
  }
  
  console.log(queue);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="addElement(11501,10);">Add item1 to queue</button>
<button type="button" onclick="addElement(11502,10);">Add item2 to queue</button>
```

Comment: Exactly :) what I was looking for

Comment: since you're converting some strings form the backend into json objects some numerical values might need parsing like Engr suggested

Answer (score 2):

You should use `parseInt()` on your quantity and then add. This will work. Currently, you are trying to add the values which are not integers. Thanks

Comment: Sadly its still a NaN hm

Comment: console.log your different variables and check that what is coming in these variables. e.g. jsonobject[e]['Ingredient1ID'] , e etc etc

Comment: Object {11001: NaN, 11501: NaN, 12012: NaN, 13001: NaN}

Comment: console.log(jsonobject[e]['Ingredient1ID'] + " " + jsonobject[e]['Ingredient1Quantity']); = 11001 2

Comment: May you post your tag on which ONCLICK event is binding and your requirement, so that we can teak it to get your desired result.

Comment: example added check it